# Wildfly EJB Deployment With Shared Library

Tags: java, maven, ejb, wildfly, ear

I'm in the process of trying to set up a project to deploy to a wildfly 18 server using the maven-wildfly plugin. The project is composed of an EJB ear for each application and a library jar with common code that gets shared by all the applications. I started with the wildfly 'quickstart' examples to try to get an idea of what I needed to do. I found examples demonstrating deployment of an EJB ear and an example of how to deploy intercommunicating apps with a shared lib. What I can't seem to wrap my head around is how to combine the two. When I try to deploy my application, it fails with Class Not Found errors related to the Common lib.

Below is an image of my project layout. Currently, 'Person' is the only application but there will eventually be more at the same level. If I execute

> mvn clean wildfly:deploy

at the project root (optics), the deployment will fail with the message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project Person-ejb: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Person-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Person-ejb.jar\"
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.tura.person.service.test.TestBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.Person-ejb.jar\" from Service Module Loader
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/tura/person/service/ClientServiceProvider (Module \"deployment.Person-ejb.jar\" from Service Module Loader): com/tura/common/service/login/LoginService"}}}}
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project Person-ejb: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Person-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Person-ejb.jar\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.tura.person.service.test.TestBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.Person-ejb.jar\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/tura/person/service/ClientServiceProvider (Module \"deployment.Person-ejb.jar\" from Service Module Loader): com/tura/common/service/login/LoginService"}}}}
```

Rather than post the text off all the poms here, I created a quick github repo here: https://github.com/pbtura/optics-maven . There is also an abridged version of the files that are mentioned in the exception. If anyone can take a look and give me some suggestions of what I might be doing wrong I would be grateful.

**Project Layout:**

[image]

**Update:**
I decided to go back to basics to try to narrow down the cause of my issues. I copied one of the existing quickstart projects and added a shared library. I got the same results, but I was able to determine that the problem is related to the EJB injection rather than the classpath. If I remove the annotations from my interface and bean and make them straight POJOs the project compiles and deploys.

If anyone wants to see the complete code and try building it for yourself, I uploaded it to another repo here: https://github.com/pbtura/ejb-inter-app

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell as that project doesn't build. However it looks like you're likely missing an inner dependency. How do you deploy the `Common.jar`?

Comment: @James R. Perkins Common.jar gets deploy as part of the maven build as a jar in the lib/ directory of the Person.ear. If it helps I created another repo here: https://github.com/pbtura/ejb-inter-app with code that actually builds.

Comment: I don't see where the shared JAR is added as a dependency to any of the modules in the EAR. It's not added as a dependency to the EAR either so it won't end up in the lib directory.